# Why are pickled plums 梅干 and not 梅漬, etc?

Tags: words, kanji, food, kanji-choice

What caused pickled plums to be referenced with kanji indicating dryness? Could it be that the word itself holds some form of seniority over the kanji? My quick Wikipedia skimming does not seem to imply that 梅干 are dried and then pickled, or pickled and then dry- although I have missed simple technicalities like this is the past.. So what gives? Shouldn't they be called 漬け梅, or some similar term?

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact, there is a food called 梅漬. The difference between 梅干 and 梅漬 is that 梅干 is made by drying the plums in the sun and then pickling them in salt, while 梅漬 is made without any drying in the sun.

Comment: Isn't it pickled and then dried?

Comment: @aguijonazo afaik no. my mother used to cook 梅干 and that didn't happen.

Comment: ... So I googled it and well, it was pickled and then dried and then pickled. I guess I missed the first pickled-dried part?

Comment: I guess there could be different methods, but considering how much water there is in plums, it is probably difficult to sun-dry them before pickling them. Even using the normal method of pickling first, it is quite easy to get mold growth.